# EXCEL - Count number of dates in a month

Tags: excel, date, count

I have a long list of dates, and for each date I would like to determine how many references in the list of dates occur in the same month **and year**.

For example, for the list below:

```
27/06/2015
04/07/2015
11/07/2015
18/07/2015
25/07/2015
01/08/2015
08/08/2015
15/08/2015
22/08/2015
29/08/2015
```

Based on e.g. 4/7/2015, there is a total of 4 dates in the list which occur in the same month and year as the said date. Or, for 8/8/2015, there is a total of 5 dates in the list which occur in the same month and year.

Please can someone help me write a formula, thanks!

Comment: Can we assume that your regional version of Excel is parsing dates as dd/mm/yyyy as opposed to mm/dd/yyyy like we do in North America (I agree its a stupid order)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways to do this: Helper columns, or Array Formulas. I will show the Helper Column method, which in this case is quite straightforward.

Assuming your data is in column A starting at A2, in column B starting at B2 put the following and drag down:

```
=YEAR(A2)&MONTH(A2)
```

This will create a unique ID which shows just the YEAR & MONTH to be compared against. Then in Column C, starting at C2, put the following:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(B2,$B$1:B1,0)),COUNTIF(B:B,B2),"")
```

For all unique values in B2 [the new Unique ID we created], it will put the count of how many times that YEAR/MONTH combo appears.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Bacon's response this is the array formula method. Assuming your data is in column A and the date you are comparing with is `ReferenceDate` then your calculation would be:

```
{=SUM(IF(MONTH(A:A)=MONTH(ReferenceDate),1,0)*IF(YEAR(A:A)=YEAR(ReferenceDate),1,0))}
```

Note this is inputted by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` to create an array formula. Regards,